# SQL delete query ignoring errors and continue

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

Doing this:

```
delete from product 
where descricao ilike '%ACC%'
```

I get this error:

> update or delete on table "product" violates foreign key constraint "fk3b140f7bc8c91aae" on table "productmoviment"

I need to query continue and execute all the lines, deleting the ones which don't have, because if one single line has a foreign key it doesn't execute any other at all

Thanks

Comment: Please add a tag for the database you're using - this might quite probably depend on the database used.

Comment: Also, what is the expected outcome, i.e. what should happen with those rows that are referenced by other table(s)? It might be best to either define the references as `ON DELETE CASCADE|SET NULL` or include a condition in your `where` that checks that there is not reference to the record in the referencing table(s).

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is something like a one-time cleanup operation: otherwise you have to make sure your foreign keys are correctly defined.

You can do it using a anonymous stored procedure.

Assumption:

- the product table has a primary key called id

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    pr product%rowtype;
BEGIN
      FOR pr IN 
      select * from product
      where descricao ilike '%ACC%'
      LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'trying to delete product id  %',pr.id;
          BEGIN
              DELETE FROM product WHERE id=pr.id;
              RAISE NOTICE 
              'Deleted product id: %',pr.id;
          EXCEPTION
              WHEN others THEN 
                  -- we ignore the error
              END;
      END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Basically it iterates on all the products matching the WHERE clause (descricao ilike '%ACC%') and tries to delete them one-by-one, ignoring errors for products that cannot be deleted due to foreign keys.

Answer (score -1):

To delete this, you have to define the foreign key constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE.`

`CASCADE` defines that when a referenced row is deleted, it automatically deleted  referencing rows as well

read [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

But there is another way 
You have to delete a foreign key 1st then delete parent table

```
 delete from childtable
 where id_parent = 1;-- child table

 DELETE FROM parent
  WHERE id_parent = 1; --parent table
```